# Programmatically add customer to order during "sales_order_place_before" event

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, customer-account

I have a situation where I am trying to associate a customer membership to an order during the `sales_order_place_before` event.

I though it would be pretty straightforward, however, whenever I try to attach a customer ID the order does not retain this information.

Can someone tell me specifically what needs to occur in order to assign a customer during the `sales_order_place_before` event.

If this event is not feasible, can someone tell me the correct way to go about what it is I am doing?

Comment: Please post the content of your observer. Chances are that you will need to add the customer id to quote. I am guessing you are adding it to the order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to used magento event "sales_order_place_after".
In that event observer you can change the order customer using this code.

```
$order_id = YOUR_ORDER_ID;  
$customer_id = CUSTOMER_ID;  

$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$_order->setCustomerId($customer_id);
$_order->save();
```